# WAMP Server, started getting 403 forbidden response from Android activity

Tags: android, apache

I have a web service which is hosted on my WAMP Server. URL: http://localhost/appname/service.php

I have an Android application which calls methods of the web service.

In LogCat I can see the response is a generic HTML page saying 403 Forbidden, you do not have access to the page etc, however when I go to the URL which the Android code called I can access the service just fine.

In the Apache error log I have

```
AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/appname/service.php
```

How come I can access the URL directly through my browser but not through my device? Both are on the same wifi network.

This was working previous (for the past month).

Answer (score -1):

First tip: Your networking job should be made inside AsyncTask instead of an Activity. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Second tip: How are you building your HTTP request?

Comment: First tip: I am using AsyncTask. Second task: As stated the URL is fine if I paste it into browser. I solved this by putting the wamp server offline, stop/start services then put it back online. Thanks anyway